# How to make JTable cell editable/noneditable dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any way to make non editable cell dynamically in jtable ? Whenever user gives input like false, i want to make non editable cell...I have seen in DefaultTableModel isCellEditable method.But if i want to use that i have create each time new object.So i want to change it non editable dynamically. Can you anyone please  help me?..thanks

Comment: What input? Into what? I'm sorry, but your question is some what vague and unclear.  Yes you can change the state of a cell's editability dynamically, you need to supply your own table model, but it's very doable.  I change the state of cells or the time based on the values of other cells...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
public class MyDefaultTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    private boolean[][] editable_cells; // 2d array to represent rows and columns

    private MyDefaultTableModel(int rows, int cols) { // constructor
        super(rows, cols);
        this.editable_cells = new boolean[rows][cols];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { // custom isCellEditable function
        return this.editable_cells[row][column];
    }

    public void setCellEditable(int row, int col, boolean value) {
        this.editable_cells[row][col] = value; // set cell true/false
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

other class

```
... stuff
DefaultTableModel myModel = new MyDefaultTableModel(x, y); 
table.setModel(myModel);
... stuff
```

You can then set the values dynamically by using the myModel variable you have stored and calling the setCellEditable() function on it.. in theory. I have not tested this code but it should work. You may still have to fire some sort of event to trigger the table to notice the changes.

Comment: minor quirks: a) java supports ... boolean types :-) No need to use magic ints as a stand-in b) agree that you should fire an update on the cell (if the editability changed), as applications might render cells based on their editability

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems to figure out how to enable/disable editing of a cell dynamically (in my case based on occurences in a database.) I did it like this:

```
jTableAssignments = new javax.swing.JTable() {
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
    return editable;
}};
```

That of course overrides isCellEditable. The only way I could make that work by the way, was to add the declaration to the instantiation of the tabel itself and not the table model.

Then I declared editable as a private boolean that can be set e.g.:

```
    private void jTableAssignmentsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    if(jTableAssignments.getSelectedRow() == 3 & jTableAssignments.getSelectedColumn() == 3) {
        editable = true;
    }
    else {
        editable = false;
    } 

}
```

And it works quite well.