# Java- how do I make the cells in a JTable editable?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable

I have a `JTable` displayed in my GUI- currently, when the program loads, the table is completely empty- showing only the column headings (there isn't even an empty table there).

I have a button which, when clicked, will add a new empty row to the table, underneath the column headings. However, although I can select each of the individual cells added to the table, I cannot type anything into them.

I am adding the row to the table using the following code:

```
/*Create the button, and add an ActionListener to it */
JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
});

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
    System.out.println("Add button pressed. ");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();

    Object[] obj = new Object[]{};
    model.addRow(obj);
}
```

This code currently works- as mentioned, whenever I click the button, a new row is added to the table, and I can select each individual cell.

What do I need to do to make the selected cell editable? I have another button ('Edit'), which I want the user to be able to click when they have selected a cell from the table, and once they have clicked it, they should be able to type data into the cell. But I'm not sure how to do this, and couldn't find anything online about how to add this functionality to a button in the GUI.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make JTable cell editable/noneditable dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776021/how-to-make-jtable-cell-editable-noneditable-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { 
    return true; 
}
```

You may replace `true` with a variable that you may toggle

Comment: Yep- just spotted this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an action button which receives the column and row as input received from a JOptionPane.
Let the use then edit the cell with another JOptionPane.